# Devo usar um docker-compose.yml ou vários

Tags: docker, microsserviços

Bom dia,

A arquitetura do meu projeto é de micro-serviços que estão em containers docker. Em que tenho um ficherio docker-compose.yml para todos os micro-serviços.

A minha questão é:
É melhor ter um ficheiro docker-compose.yml para todos os micro-serviços ou devo ter um ficheiro docker-compose por cada micro-serviço?

Obrigado

Comment: eu particulamente prefiro a ideia de cada serviço ter o seu compose, até pq, tudo junto meio que fere a ideia de micro serviços, mas tem o incoveninete de repetir várias infrastrutras compartilhadas, e a resposta do tvdias dá uma boa solução pra isso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Apesar de achar que é o tipo de resposta que será baseada em opiniões, acredito que possa ser útil para muitas pessoas, caso sejam compartilhadas sugestões para esse problema.*

Já passei por essa situação, onde tenho um ambiente com mais de 30 serviços. Neste caso optei por ter diversos `docker-compose`s. Em cada um dos arquivos tenho somente o serviço especificado no nome do compose e dependências **exclusivas** deste serviço. Um exemplo de dependência exclusiva são serviços de inicialização de dados para testes e DB migration, pois temos isso fora dos nossos serviços.

Como cada serviço tem o seu database, inicialmente criamos um DB em cada yml, junto com o serviço, entretanto, como todos usam o mesmo servidor de base de dados, optamos posteriormente por criar um compose "base" (ou de "infrastrutura"), onde adicionamos serviços como message bus e DBs. Esse compose base serve inclusive de "ponto de partida" para quando executamos `docker-compose up`.

Essa abordagem foi a escolhida por ser simples e "modular". Uma vez que dificilmente temos a necessidade de ter todos os serviços correndo ao mesmo tempo (usamos essa estrutura para testes em desenvolvimento). Desta forma qualquer desenvolvedor pode executar somente o compose que lhe interessa e as próprias definições no compose vão indicar as dependências necessárias para aquele serviço e o desenvolvedor pode então adicionar facilmente os demais composes ao comando.

Exemplo de `docker-compose up`:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml `
               -f part_servico_a.yml `
               -f part_servico_b.yml `
               up -d
```

Neste exemplo temos toda a parte de infra estrutura no `docker-compose.yml` e as aplicações nos `part_servico_X.yml`. Caso um desses serviços dependa de um outro serviço o comando apresentará o erro de forma clara e então podemos adicionar `-f part_servico_X.yml` ao comando.

Exemplo de `docker-compose.yml` base:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  cassandra:
    image: cassandra
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"

  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
     - 2181

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

Exemplo de `part_servico_X.yml`:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  servico-X:
    image: <IMAGEM>
    restart: on-failure
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 60s
    depends_on:
      - cassandra
      - cassandra-migration-servico-X
      - servico-Y
      - servico-Z

  cassandra-migration-servico-X:
    image: <IMAGEM>
    depends_on:
      - cassandra
```

Answer (score -3):

Mantendo múltiplos .yml você consegue manter o principio da coesão dos micro-serviços, ou seja, somente estará no .yml o necessário para a execução. Você pode orquestrar diversos micro-serviços subindo conforme o @tvdias citou e pensando em utilização de um service mesh como Istio, faz ainda mais sentido manter isso separado.

De qualquer forma, essa é uma decisão de projeto conceitual, ambas as formas funcionariam, mas provavelmente seja mais fácil de manter isolando esses .ymls.